# proof involving Cauchy sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Is there a proof of the following statement?

A sequence $(x_n)$ has a Cauchy subsequence if and only if it has a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ for which $d(x_{n_k}, x_{n_{k+1}}) < \frac{1}{2^k}$ for all $k$.

Comment: What have you tried so far? An "if and only if" statement has two directions; have you proved one of the directions yet?

Comment: It looks to me like it follows almost immediately from the **definition** of "Cauchy sequence".   What is that definition?

Comment: Ali, can you show that $\frac{1}{2^{k}}<\frac{1}{n}$ by induction? If so, then by the Archimedean property you will have that  $\frac{1}{2^{k}}<\varepsilon$ and so it would be clear to you what you want to exactly prove.

Comment: Do you mean $2^{-n} < 1/n$?

Comment: Sorry, I meant $2^{-k}<1/k$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence such that a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ has the property you mention. Choose $\epsilon>0$ and let $k_0$ be such that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=k_0}^{+\infty}2^{-k}<\epsilon.
\end{equation}
If $i,j\geq k_0$ and $j>i$, then by triangular inequality
\begin{equation}
d(x_{n_i},x_{n_j})\leq\sum_{k=i}^{j-1}d(x_{n_k},x_{n_{k+1}})<\sum_{k=i}^{j-1}2^{-k}<\sum_{k=k_0}^{+\infty}2^{-k}<\epsilon.
\end{equation}
That is: $(x_{n_k})$ is the Cauchy subsequence you were looking for.

Conversely, assume that $(x_n)$ has a Cauchy subsequence and, without loss of generality, assume that this subsequence is $(x_n)$ itself. We construct $(x_{n_k})$ inductively. First, let $n_1$ be such that $d(x_n,x_m)<2^{-1}$ for all $n,m\geq n_1$. Suppose you have already determined $n_1,\dots,n_k$. Let $n_{k+1}$ be such that $n_{k+1}\geq n_k$ and $d(x_n,x_m)<2^{-(k+1)}$ for all $n,m\geq n_{k+1}$. Since both $n_k$ and $n_{k+1}$ are greater than or equal to $n_k$, one clearly has $d(x_{n_k},x_{n_{k+1}})<2^{-k}$ and the proof is finished.